# set date in textbox by value coming from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
 <input name="Release" id="rdate" type="text"  class="input datepicker" value="@entry.Release"/>
```

I want to display only that value in textbox. While  @entry.Release contain date from databse and it should be visible in textbox as default date. Its showing current date in my textbox but I haave to show that belongs to @entry.Release whatever I have declared in my above code.   @entry.Release contain date from databse and it should be visible in textbox as default date

Comment: please post your code. Otherwise it's quite difficult to get any help.

Comment: Can you just elaborate your question,please...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `@entry.Release` is not null?

try changing

```
value=@entry.Release
```

to

```
value=@Model.Release.ToString()
```